# WebSocket from Python to Nuxt 3 client

Tags: python, websocket, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Im trying to create a websocket connection from `python.py` to `index.vue`.

I can't establish a connection on page load.

Index.vue -> model.post.ts -> python.py -> *(websocket)* -> index.vue

I want to send data from `python.py` while in process to the `index.vue` client to provide live updates which is where i'm stuck.

Reference YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-LSN-xo6N4 
with referenced GitHub https://github.com/adityar15/nuxt3socket/tree/master

```
"@types/uuid": "^9.0.4",
"@types/ws": "^8.5.6"
```

**/index.vue**

```js
<div>message: {{ message }}</div>


import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

const uid = uuid()
const message = ref<string>("")
const { $socket } = useNuxtApp()

onMounted(() => {
    $socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket is open now.')
        localStorage.setItem(`connection-${uid}`, uid)
        $socket.send(uid)
    }

    // $socket.onmessage = ({ data }: any) => {
    //     console.log("data:", data)
    //     message.value = data
    // }

    $socket.onclose = function () {
        console.log("disconnected")
    }
```

**/plugins/websocket.client.ts**

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  if (process.server) return

  const wsProtocol = window.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss:" : "ws:"
  let socket = new WebSocket(`${wsProtocol}//${window.location.host}`)
  
  return {
    provide: {
      socket,
    },
  }
})
```

**/server/middleware/socket.ts**

```js
import WebSocket, { WebSocketServer } from "ws"

type Client = {
  id: string
  send: (message: string) => void
  readyState: number
}

declare global {
  var wss: WebSocketServer
  //var clients: Client[]
}

let wss: WebSocketServer
//let clients: Client[] = []

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {

  if (!global.wss) {
    wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: (event.node.res.socket as any)?.server })
    wss.on("connection", function (socket) {
      console.log('New connection established.')

      socket.send("connected")

      socket.on("error", function (error) {
        console.log(`Socket Error: ${error}`);
      });

    wss.on("error", function (error) {
      console.log(`WebSocket Server Error: ${error}`);
    });

    global.wss = wss
  }
})
```

**data.py**

`pip install websocket-client`

```py
from websocket import create_connection

ws_url = 'ws://localhost:3000'
print(f"Attempting to connect to {ws_url}")
ws = create_connection(ws_url)
print("WebSocket connection established.")

def send_progress_data(data):
    print('sending progress data...')
    message = f"data: {data}" 
    ws.send(message)
    print(f"Sent: {message}")

...
```

Im not receiving any error messages but not establishing a connection